# QTreeView stylesheets: смена внешнего вида заголовка столбца

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qtreeview

Я хочу поменять внешний вид строчки "Name", но не знаю, как именно называется данная часть виджета *QTreeView*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `QHeaderView`? Можно получить через `QTreeView::header()`